# Ways to use array in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hello I am having a tought time figuring out how to use arrays in cakephp. right now i have a view with 2 columns, active and startYear. i need to grab the start years for all of the columns in the view and sho i have this code.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->setTable('odb.SchoolYear');   

}
```

controller

```
public function index()
{
    $deleteTable = $this->loadModel('DeletedTranscripts');

    $this->$deleteTable->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'field' => 500,
            'status' => 'Confirmed'
        ),
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    $this->set('startYear',$deleteTable );
}
```

once i have the array captured and put into lets say startYear can in input a statement like this into my dropdown list to populate it?

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?= $delete->startYear; ?></a>
  </div>
```

i have been looking for answers for quite awhile any help would be awesome.

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: There's not a single array anywhere in this question. You do a `find`, but don't assign the result (which is a `Query` object, not an array, though both can be iterated over) anywhere. Then you set a view variable called `startYear` to be the table object. Then in your view you try to reference a variable called `delete` that was never set. These all demonstrate a lack of understanding of the basics of CakePHP which the tutorial might help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

### Loading Tables in CakePHP

For this line:

```
$deleteTable = $this->loadModel('DeletedTranscripts');
```

While you can get a table this way, there's really no reason to set the return of loadModel to a variable. This function sets a *property* of the same name on the Controller, which almost correctly used on the next line. Just use:

```
$this->loadModel('DeletedTranscripts');
```

Then you can start referencing this Table with:

```
$this->DeletedTranscripts
```

Additionally, if you're in say the `DeletedTranscriptsController` - the corresponding Table is loaded for you automatically, this call might be unnecessary entirely.

### Getting Query Results

Next, you're close on the query part, you've can start to build a new Query with:

```
 $this->DeletedTranscripts->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'field' => 500,
            'status' => 'Confirmed'
        ),
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));
```

But note that the `find()` function does not immediately return results - it's just building a query. You can continue to modify this query with additional functions (like `->where()` or `->contain()`).

To get results from a query you need to call something like `toArray()` to get all results or `first()` to get a single one, like so:

```
$deletedTranscriptsList = $this->DeletedTranscripts->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'field' => 500,
        'status' => 'Confirmed'
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC'
))->toArray();
```

### Sending data to the view

Now that you've got the list, set that so it's available in your view as an array:

```
$this->set('startYear', $deletedTranscriptsList );
```

### **See also:**

- [Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)
- [Setting View Variables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables)

I also noticed you've had a few other related questions recently - CakePHP's docs are really good overall, it does cover these systems pretty well. I'd encourage you to read up as much as possible on Controller's & View's.

I'd also maybe suggest running through the [CMS Tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/installation.html) if you've not done so already, the section covering Controllers might help explain a number of CakePHP concepts related here & has some great working examples.

Hope this helps!